# How to 'sqlite3' run after build exe with electron-builder

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have build my electron app with help of https://medium.com/jspoint/packaging-and-distributing-electron-applications-using-electron-builder-311fc55178d9

it was was success (windows only). but after install published app, i am getting error as shown in screenshort

[image]

my scripts as below

package.json

```
  "name": "aux-services",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Mobile Repair Tracking System",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
      "pack": "electron-builder -w"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/shafeequeot/Mobile-Service-Tracker.git"
  },
  "author": "AuxWall",
  "email": "shafeequeot@gmail.com",
  "url": "https://auxwall.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/shafeequeot/Mobile-Service-Tracker/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/shafeequeot/Mobile-Service-Tracker#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.13",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   
  }
}
```

electron-builder.json

```
{
    "appId": "com.auxWall.service",

    "productName": "Aux Services",
    "copyright": "AuxWall",
    "directories": {
        "app": ".",
        "output": "out",
        "buildResources": "build-res"
    },
    "files": [
        "package.json",
        "**/*",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "dmg": {
        "background": null,
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "window": {
            "width": "400",
            "height": "300"
        },
        "contents": [
            {
                "x": 100,
                "y": 100
            },
            {
                "x": 300,
                "y": 100,
                "type": "link",
                "path": "/Applications"
            }
        ]
    },
    "mac": {
        "target": "dmg",
        "category": "public.auxWall.services"
      },
    "win": {
        "target": "nsis"
    },
    "linux": {
        "target": "AppImage",
        "category": "Utility"
    }
}
```

can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sqlite3` is required during normal operation of your Electron application and not just during development then you will need to added `sqlite3` as a dependency.

IE: Move `"sqlite3": "^5.0.2"` from `"devDependencies": { ... }` to `"dependencies": { ... }`.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "aux-services",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Mobile Repair Tracking System",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
      "pack": "electron-builder -w"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/shafeequeot/Mobile-Service-Tracker.git"
  },
  "author": "AuxWall",
  "email": "shafeequeot@gmail.com",
  "url": "https://auxwall.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/shafeequeot/Mobile-Service-Tracker/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/shafeequeot/Mobile-Service-Tracker#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"   
  }
}
```